# Assert json matches using Yesod.Test

Tags: json, haskell, integration-testing, yesod, yesod-test

I wan't to get a resource from my yesod app and assert it matches a known JSON value.

I can see that in `Yesod.Test.Json` there is the function `assertJSON` with the type

```
assertJSON :: (ToJSON a, FromJSON a) => (a -> (String, Bool)) -> SResponse -> Session ()
```

But there is no example usage and I can't work out how this is used from the type alone.

How would I be able to check that the JSON returned from my yesod app matches?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you acquire an `SResponse` in a `Session` do block as per https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-test-0.1.1/docs/Network-Wai-Test.html (googled `SResponse` and checked that the module matched one imported by https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-test-json-0.2.0.0/docs/src/Yesod-Test-Json.html), choose a type `a` that you want to assert the JSON to encode, construct a function `a -> (String, Bool)` whose second argument specifies whether your desired property holds and whose first argument specifies the error to output otherwise (should have been `a -> Either String Bool` imo) (checked the source), then apply `assertJSON` to the function and the `SResponse` within that same do block to express the assertion.